# How to get the inference compute graph of the pytorch model?

Tags: pytorch, onnx

I want to hand write a framework to perform inference of a given neural network. The network is so complicated, so to make sure my implementation is correct, I need to know how exactly the inference process is done on device.

I tried to use `torchviz` to visualize the network, but what I got seems to be the back propagation compute graph, which is really hard to understand.

[image]

Then I tried to convert the pytorch model to ONNX format, following the instruction [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/ai/windows-ml/tutorials/pytorch-convert-model), but when I tried to visualize it, it seems that the original layers of the model had been seperated into very small operators.

[image]

I just want to get the result like this
[image]

How can I get this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried saving the model with `torch.save` (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html) and opening it with [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron)? The last view you showed is a view of the Netron app.

Answer (score 1):

You can try also the package **torchview**, which provides several features (useful especially for large models). For instance you can set the display depth (depth in nested hierarchy of moduls).
It is also based on forward prop

[github repo](https://github.com/mert-kurttutan/torchview)

Disclaimer: I am the author of the package

Note: The accepted format for tool is pytorch model